# Изолировать плагин от внешних css

Tags: css, wordpress, html5, плагин, wp-plugin

Есть плагин, который выводит слайдер. Если проверять без установки, т.е. сам html код работает отлично. 
Если в стилях темы прописано li{color:blue;}, то это будет работать и для html кода плагина. Мне нужно оградить html код плагина от стилей темы.

Собствено, как отключить для плагина наследование стилей темы ?

Comment: а что именно этот плагин наследует ?

Comment: стили установленой темы. Мне нужно чтобы он использовал только собственные.

Comment: ну это обычный css, вы с ним знакомы ?

Comment: Вроде да. Но проблема в том что наследование происходит автоматически.
Т.е. у плагина есть свой сss который я подключил. после вставки на страницу wp идет наследование ее стилей. Редактировать стили темы под плагин не вариант.

Comment: а что происходит при наследовании ?

Comment: используються стили темы. Если в стилях темы прописано 
    li{color:blue;} то это будет работать и для html кода плагина. Мне нужно оградить  html код плагина от стилей темы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40121/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-m-ivashchuk).

Comment: Используй классы.... расставь в css плагина классы и стилизуй по ним.

Comment: стилизация и происходит по класам, дело в том что если в сss темы прописаны стили для тегов(p{}), то они будут влиять и на плагин, а мне это не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Единственный способ - использовать shadow dom. Но его [поддержка браузерами](//caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom) совсем не впечатляет. Так что надо просто по-человечески писать достаточно конкретные стили.